# Is notification of threads guaranteed for std::call_once after exceptional call

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The standard example for `std::call_once` on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) describes the behavior for exceptional calls that way, that to my understanding other threads wait for the first entering the `std::call_once` and in case of an exception the next thread will try to execute the `std::call_once`. While online compilers confirm this behavior, I cannot reproduce it locally. For the minimal example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag flag;

void may_throw_function(bool do_throw)
{
  if (do_throw) {
    std::cout << "throw: call_once will retry\n";
    throw std::exception();
  }
  std::cout << "Didn't throw, call_once will not attempt again\n";
}

void do_once(bool do_throw)
{
  try {
    std::call_once(flag, may_throw_function, do_throw);
  }
  catch (...) {}
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(do_once, true);
    std::thread t2(do_once, true);
    std::thread t3(do_once, false);
    std::thread t4(do_once, true);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

copied from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) the execution is stuck after the first throw and runs forever

Compilation is done with `g++-5 -std=c++14 source.cpp -pthread` (version `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609`) or `clang++-6.0 source.cpp -pthread` (version `clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)`).

Putting more output into the code shows, that all threads are started, but only the threads that throws first ever ends. All others seems to wait before the `std::call_once` statement. Hence my question: Is the notification of threads that are waiting for the first thread to finish guaranteed?

Comment: Wait. I overlooked the question. What notification? Do you mean "is `t1.join()` guaranteed to return?"

Comment: It seems there bugs in GCC... GCC  4.8.4 just throw `std::system_error` when trying to call `std::call_once`.

Comment: @YSC In fact for me only one of the threads with exceptional execution seems to return, all others continue forever, so the other `tx.join()` for `x` being 2, 3 or 4 do never return.

Comment: Well I believe that it is guaranteed in a conforming implementation, but libstdc++ and pthread are buggy, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66146 and https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18435.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the notification of threads that are waiting for the first thread to finish guaranteed?

There is no notification involved, but if I interpret your question as:

> Is `t4.join()` guaranteed to return?

Yes it is.

> #### [`[thread.once.callonce]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.once.callonce)
>
> ```
> template<class Callable, class... Args>
>  void call_once(once_flag& flag, Callable&& func, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: An execution of `call_­once` that does not call its func is a passive execution.
>   An execution of `call_­once` that calls its func is an active execution.
>   An active execution shall call `INVOKE(​std::forward<Callable>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.
>   If such a call to func throws an exception the execution is exceptional, otherwise it is returning.
>   An exceptional execution shall propagate the exception to the caller of `call_­once`.
>   Among all executions of `call_­once` for any given `once_­flag`: at most one shall be a returning execution; if there is a returning execution, it shall be the last active execution; and **there are passive executions only if there is a returning execution**.
>
> *Synchronization*: For any given once_­flag: **all active executions occur in a total order**; completion of an active execution synchronizes with the start of the next one in this total order; and the returning execution synchronizes with the return from all passive executions.

A `call_once` will not be executed **only if** another `call_once` returned (meaning: did not throw). And since total order is observed, it is guaranteed that:

- `t1` is an active exceptional execution or a passive execution;
- `t2` is an active exceptional execution or a passive execution;
- `t3` is an active returning execution;
- `t4` is an active exceptional execution or a passive execution;

And since a passive execution returns, `t4` is guaranteed to return.

---

Reported by [user cpplearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner), [a bug of `pthread_once`](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18435) make the program listed in the question hang ([demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ae70efc9640a772)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to admit, that they question is kind of vague. This is because for me locally the program *never* exits. So for me one of the threads is an active exceptional execution, while all other seem not to do an active nor a passive execution. Could you reproduce the behavior? I am afraid that something on my system causes the unexpected behavior...